Need to convert a Visual studio C++ project to a Cmake
I have a c++ code repo it has almost 68 projects within it. It was initially created using MSVC. I need to build that same project with gcc using cmake. Is there a way to convert that to a CMAKE project. It has a lot of dependencies that come from Microsoft. Please advise of any technic.

You need to use g++ for C++.  The gcc is for C language.
